# How to access google authentication cookie in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new at reactjs. In my app i have used google oauth. I'm using **"react-google-login"**  node package to manage that. There is no problem with login but, i can't log out. I have tried many things including "react-cookie" but I couldn't log out. In my opinion to log out I need to delete google authentication cookie which is created by GoogleLogin component. Is there any way to access and delete cookies despite of localhost cookies?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWE1t.png)

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login). It has an example of how to logout.